# Are constraints in overload resolution affected by difference it type qualifiers?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Having the following simple code:

```
#include <concepts>

auto f(const auto&) { }
auto f(std::integral auto) {}

int main() 
{ 
    f(5); 
}
```

[We have an ambiguous call](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5cxn88rbE) with clang & gcc but MSVC chooses the more constrained one. So far I found nothing that would support the clang's & gcc's behavior. So is it a bug in both compilers or there is something that makes this call ambiguous?

Comment: I see the ambiguity. here 5 is both `const` and matches the concept. I mean, what is "more constrained". The one with the concept? But that's not marked `const&`. So it's "constrained differently".

Comment: This is because [GCC-11](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;h=57b4daf8dc4ed7b669cc70638866ddb00f5b7746) implements [p2113](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2113r0.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without considering constraints, the call is ambiguous because the first overload is deduced to a function parameter type `const int&` and the second to `int`. Neither will be considered better than the other when called with a prvalue of type `int` and neither `const auto&` or `auto` are more specialized in usual partial ordering of templates either.

According to [[temp.func.order]/6.2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.func.order#6.2.2) constraints on function templates are not taken into account if the types of the function parameters after substitution from template argument deduction do not correspond.

Here the first overload deduced the function parameter to `const int&` and the second to `int`. These are not equal. And so partial ordering of the templates will not consider either more specialized than the other based on any constraints either.

Comment: But the deduced types are the same. You can rewrite the code to use `template<typename T>` instead of `auto`. In both cases template parameter will be `T` and the argument will be `int`. Both clang & gcc in their errors actually says, that `auto` is `int`.

Comment: @ixSci That's not what I meant. I fixed the wording.